# Does the Excel solver actually know the objective formula?

Tags: c#, excel, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for a solver that emulates best the Excel solver (GRG-nonlinear), which works in the following way:
 1. You define which cells he shall use as variables.
 2. You define the constraints i. e. C3 < 5.
 3. You define a goal cell, which should be minimized or maximized.

From my understanding, the Excel solver does not know the functions that connect the variables, constraints and goal cell with one another. It merely alter the variable cells and looks how the goal cell changes.
Is this assumption correct?
If yes, does a similar flexibel solver exist for C# i. e. one that changes the variables, let's you send them through your formulas and hand him back the objective value?

Comment: Did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

GRG is a nonlinear solver by Leon Lasdon using a Generalized Reduced Gradient method. I think you can purchase this solver from solver.com. There are other good NLP solvers around such as Conopt, Snopt, Minos, Knitro, Ipopt. Some of them have C# APIs. For complex models, it may be easier to use a Modeling Language such as AMPL or GAMS in between (they provide a more structured, high-level modeling interface including automatic differentiation).